# popViewController does not update correctly

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, viewwillappear

I have a application that has a navigation controller. View1 -> View2 -> View3. When I am at View3 if I perform a popViewController on a button, it sends me back to the View2 but the view is not presented as expected. On this View2 I have a scrollView and some other labels. The first time the app runs everything is presented OK and if from the View3 I hit the back button on the top navigation bar everything is also presented correctly.

(The view2 is being loaded on the viewWilAppear Method).

Can anyone give me some hints to solve this?

Thanks
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

When you pop a view from the navigation tree, viewWilAppear: is called again. If needed try to load the view on viewDidLoad that will only be called once

Comment: The problem is that if I load it on the ViewDidLoad Method (View2), the second time it loads there are some fields that need to be updated depending on actions that were performed on the View3. If I use the ViewDidLoad it will not refresh those values.

Comment: I see. Maybe part of it will need to be on viewWillAppear: and the other on viewDidLoad. Maybe you'll need a flag to see if changes have already been performed. You'd set it as NO once view 3 appears and to YES when you update the view